# Bind ASP.NET MVC model value to checkbox with knockout.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am new to knockout.js. I have a Y/N value from my model that I want to bind to a checkbox.

This is my view:

```
<tbody id="tblMultiEdit" data-bind="foreach: UUTs">
<tr>
<td data-bind="text: SerialNumber"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="ReqDowngrade" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="ACTSupported"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="ProdModeOff"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Knockout code:

```
function ViewModel(UUTs) 
{

var self = this;

self.UUTs = UUTs;

};

var viewModel = new ViewModel(@Html.HtmlConvertToJson(Model));

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

So far I can bind the text with no problem, but checkboxes are in blank.

Comment: this one is incorrect `data-bind="ReqDowngrade"` Find how to bind inputs values here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

Comment: Thanks, now I need a way to convert Y/N to 0/1 within knockout for each row

Comment: can u update question with code u have now?

Comment: I resolved it. See answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by adding a ternary operation.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: (ReqDowngrade == 'Y' ? 1 : 0)" /></td>
```

If anybody knows a more efficient way using knockout let me know!